# Running psql from shell always ask for connection details

Tags: windows, postgresql

I am trying to run psql command from windows command line. However, command always ask for connection details even though connection details are given.

I have tried below two commands but none works:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\scripts\runpsql.bat -f d:\test.sql postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/testdb
```

and

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\scripts\runpsql.bat" -h localhost -d testdb -U postgres -p 5432 -f d:\test.sql
```

I have created password file to store password as mentioned [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html).

However, in command line, it asks for host name, database and other details.

Comment: Can you quote `runpsql.bat`? That script is not part of standard PostgreSQL.

Comment: What happens if you use `"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\psql.exe"` instead of that batch file?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name - Thanks for reply. I have specify password as environment variable PGPASSWORD and then on using  command - '"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\psql.exe" -h localhost -d testdb -U postgres -p 5432 -w -a -q -l ' command line is not prompting for any details